# 4th order PDE -- Can I use Fourier transforms?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

How does one approach the PDE

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial^4 u}{\partial x^4} + u = f(x)$$

And solve it using Fourier transforms? I am not clear on the methods of solving 4th order PDEs.

Comment: **Hint:** Fourier transform in $x$, then solve the 1-st order differential equation in the Fourier space for $t$. Finally transform the solution back.

Comment: So would that give something to the power of 4? I'm a bit lost truth be told